# How make sbt replace SNAPSHOT with actual date while publish to maven repository?

Tags: java, scala, maven, repository, sbt

After using command `sbt publishM2` it produces files with *SNAPSHOT* word:

```
- myProject-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
- myProject-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar.md5
- myProject-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar.sha1
- myProject-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
- myProject-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar.md5
- myProject-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar.sha1
- myProject-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
- myProject-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.md5
- myProject-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.sha1
- myProject-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
- myProject-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom.md5
- myProject-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom.sha1
```

But maven wants something like myProject-0.1.0-**20140813.192452-1**.jar instead of **SNAPSHOT** word. So maven try to downloads new jar instead of using from sbt publishing.

Is it possible to configure SBT to generate such date automatically instead of SNAPSHOT?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is limitation in Ivy and there is no configuration to avoid this problem for now.

https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1564